# $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\space\space\space f(x)-2f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x}{4})=x^2,\space\space$find $f(3)$ in terms of $f(0)$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\space\space\space\space f(x)-2f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x}{4})=x^2,\space\space\space\space$
>   Find $f(3)$ in terms of $f(0)$.

My approach:
$$f(x)-2f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x}{4})=x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\frac{x}{2})-2f(\frac{x}{4})+f(\frac{x}{8})=\frac{x^2}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\frac{x}{4})-2f(\frac{x}{8})+f(\frac{x}{16})=\frac{x^2}{16}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\Rightarrow f(\frac{x}{2^{n-1}})-2f(\frac{x}{2^n})+f(\frac{x}{2^{n+1}})=\frac{x^2}{4^{n-1}}$$

Summing up these when n $\rightarrow$ $\infty$
$$f(x)-f(\frac{x}{2})=x^2\cdot\frac{4}{3}$$

I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: I don't understand your argument in summing up. Are you assuming $f$ is additive? that is, that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution nonono...I am adding upp all these expressions in LHS from n=1 to infinity and equating with sum of all the RHSs and would get the series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/4_%2B_1/16_%2B_1/64_%2B_1/256_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is continuous at $0$? Also, can't you try the same trick i.e. add up the equations $f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac{4}{3}x^2$, $f(\tfrac{x}{2})-f(\tfrac{x}{4}) = \tfrac{1}{3}x^2$, etc.?

Comment: @ami_ba - I agree that the RHS sums up as a geometric series, but your summation is of the LHS is wrong. You cannot insert the summation into the function unless it is additive. Therefore you have a serious error in your argument.

Comment: The addition doesn't quite work out like that. You instead get $$f(x)-f\left(\frac x2\right)-2f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)+f\left(\frac x{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac43(1-4^{-n})x^2$$

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I think $f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac{4}{3}x^2$ and $f(x/2)-f(\tfrac{x}{4}) = \tfrac{1}{3}x^2$ are same

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Ummm...isn't it $f(x)-f\left(\frac x2\right)-f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)+f\left(\frac x{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac43x^2$? And when $n\rightarrow \infty$ isn't it what I wrote?

Comment: No, how do you know that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I never assumed $f(0)=0$. Is this assumption required for any step of mine?

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, $f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)\to f(0)$ but you don't seem to have $f(0)$ in your expression.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I have $+f(\frac {x}{2^{n+1}})$ and $-f(\frac {x}{2^{n}})$ both are equal to $f(0)$ and cancel each other. Please point out if there is any problem with this.

Comment: @ami_ba OK, I see what you mean. I did not notice the positive $x/2^{n+1}$ term at the start.

Comment: If you follow @JimmyK4542's method, you get that $f(3)=16+f(0)$ since $f(x)-f(0)=\frac{16}9x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go ahead and assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $P(x)$ denote the property that $f(x) - 2f(\tfrac{x}{2}) + f(\tfrac{x}{4}) = x^2$. Then, for any $x$, we have the following:

\begin{align}
P(x)&: \quad f(x) - 2f(\tfrac{x}{2}) + f(\tfrac{x}{4}) = x^2
\\
P(\tfrac{x}{2})&: \quad f(\tfrac{x}{2}) - 2f(\tfrac{x}{4}) + f(\tfrac{x}{8}) = \tfrac{1}{4}x^2
\\
& \vdots
\\
P(\tfrac{x}{2^{n-1}})&: \quad f(\tfrac{x}{2^{n-1}}) - 2f(\tfrac{x}{2^n}) + f(\tfrac{x}{2^{n+1}}) = \tfrac{1}{4^{n-1}}x^2
\end{align}

Adding these up gives us $$f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2})-f(\tfrac{x}{2^n})+f(\tfrac{x}{2^{n+1}}) = \tfrac{4}{3}(1-\tfrac{1}{4^n})x^2$$

If we take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and use the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $0$, we get $$f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2})-f(0)+f(0) = \tfrac{4}{3}(1-0)x^2$$ i.e. $$f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac{4}{3}x^2.$$

Now, we can repeat the same trick. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $Q(x)$ denote the property that $f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac{4}{3}x^2$. Then, for any $x$, we have the following:

\begin{align}
Q(x)&: \quad f(x) - f(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac{4}{3}x^2
\\
Q(\tfrac{x}{2})&: \quad f(\tfrac{x}{2}) - f(\tfrac{x}{4}) = \tfrac{1}{3}x^2
\\
& \vdots
\\
Q(\tfrac{x}{2^{n-1}})&: \quad f(\tfrac{x}{2^{n-1}}) - f(\tfrac{x}{2^n}) = \tfrac{1}{3 \cdot 4^{n-2}}x^2
\end{align}

Adding these up gives us $$f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{2^n}) = \tfrac{16}{9}(1-\tfrac{1}{4^n})x^2$$

If we take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and use the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $0$, we get $$f(x)-f(0) = \tfrac{16}{9}x^2.$$ Hence, $f(x) = \tfrac{16}{9}x^2+f(0)$. It is easy to check that any function in the form $f(x) = \tfrac{16}{9}x^2+C$ for some constant $C$ satisfies the given functional equation.

Comment: And without continuity at $0$ the task is impossible to solve, since then $f(0)$ can be defined arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

Making $y=2^x$ we have

$$
F(y)-2F(y-1)+F(y-2)=4^y
$$

which is a linear difference functional equation with solution

$$
F(y) = y \Phi_1(y)+\Phi_2(y)+\frac{4^{y+2}}{9}
$$

Here $\Phi_1(y),\Phi_2(y)$ are generic periodic functions with period $1$ Assuming $\Phi_1(y) = C_1,\Phi_2(y)= C_2$ we have

$$
f(x) = C_1\log_2 x + C_2 + \frac{16}{9}x^2
$$

then for the feasibility of $f(0)$ we have $C_1 = 0$ and

$$
f(0) = C_2
$$

and

$$
f(3) = f(0)+16
$$